# Aplicación en C# - Importación de información CSV a Base de Datos

Tags: c#, postgresql

Una pregunta, importé un archivo `CSV` con datos en un `DataGridView` y deseo guardar todos los datos en la base de datos.

La información del archivo `CSV` es la información de un reporte de asistencia y contiene datos iguales como son: el nombre e ID, solo cambian la fecha y hora, ya guarda los datos en la `BD` pero los datos que tienen la misma ID no los guarda.

¿Cómo puedo cambiar esto para que se guarden todos los datos menos los que se repitan, es decir, los mismos datos?

Este es el código que le di al botón guardar ya guarda la información, el problema es que no me avisa nada al presionar el botón guardar y cuando cambio la conexión al proveedor Npgsql ya no guarda los datos.

```
try
  {
  using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "UID=postgres;" + "PWD=1234;" + "DATABASE=ProyectoAsistencia;"))
         {
             string ConsultaSQL = "INSERT INTO reporteasistencia VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
             cn.Open();
             foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
             {
                 OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(ConsultaSQL, cn);

                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Value);
                 cmd.Parameters.Add("@p5", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);
                 //cmd.Parameters.Add("@p5", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);
             cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             }
         }
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("Reporte guardado satisfactoriamente" + ex.Message);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Muestranos el código fuente que tienes para tener una noción de que llevas de avance, de otra manera solo podemos sugerir ideas y esto se puede prolongar

Comment: ya lo agregue mi codigo

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con los datos que contienen la misma id? ¿Nos puedes facilitar la estructura de la tabla de la base de datos dónde insertas esa información? Me suena más a un problema con los campos que en el código.

Comment: Es muy probable que si tiene un ID unico, entonces no puedas repetir registros con ese ID. Me parece que aqui tienes un problema mas grande. Nota al margen, pq abres un nuevo command por cada fila, y no mejor preparas un query y despues solo le cambias los parametros?

Comment: me refiero a que en el reporte que genera el lector vienen las asistencias de todos los empleados y vienen fechas de diferentes dias que registraron su asistencia, entonces se repiten datos solo cambian las fechas y horas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si la db que usas es PostgreSQL deberias usar las clases de `NpgsqlConnection`, `NpgsqlCommand`, etc pero no usa Odbc

[npgsql library .net](http://www.npgsql.org/doc/index.html)

puedes agregar las librerias por nuget [Npgsql nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/)

Ademas deberias definir el command por fuera del foreach

```
string connstring = "DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "UID=postgres;" + "PWD=1234;" + "DATABASE=ProyectoAsistencia;";
using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(connstring))
{
    cn.Open();

    string ConsultaSQL = "INSERT INTO reporteasistencia VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(ConsultaSQL, cn);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Clear();

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[0].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p2", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p3", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p4", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[3].Value);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p5", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

como veras dentro del loop deebs hacer un `Clear()` de los parametros en cada iteracion

Para evitar duplicados debes validarlo, entoncs si existe solo aplicas un UPDATE

Entonces creas el metodo que valida si existe

```
public bool Existe(int id)
{
    string connstring = "DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "UID=postgres;" + "PWD=1234;" + "DATABASE=ProyectoAsistencia;";
    using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(connstring))
    {
        cn.Open();

        string ConsultaSQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM reporteasistencia WHERE Id = ?";
        OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand(ConsultaSQL, cn);
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p1", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = id;

        return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0;
    }
}
```

y depsues lo usas

```
string connstring = "DRIVER={PostgreSQL ANSI};" + "SERVER=localhost;" + "UID=postgres;" + "PWD=1234;" + "DATABASE=ProyectoAsistencia;";
using (OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection(connstring))
{
    cn.Open();

    string queryInsert = "INSERT INTO reporteasistencia VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    OdbcCommand cmdInsert = new OdbcCommand(queryInsert, cn);

    string queryUpdate = "UPDATE reporteasistencia SET campo = ?, ... WHERE id= ?";
    OdbcCommand cmdUpdate = new OdbcCommand(queryUpdate, cn);

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);

        if(Existe(id))
        {
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Clear();

            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@p1", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@p2", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@p3", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@p4", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
            cmdUpdate.Parameters.Add("@p5", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);

            cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        else
        {
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Clear();

            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@p1", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Value);
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@p2", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[1].Value);
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@p3", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[2].Value);
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@p4", OdbcType.Numeric).Value = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[3].Value);
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@p5", OdbcType.VarChar).Value = Convert.ToString(row.Cells[4].Value);

            cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

aplicando el Insert o Update segun corresponda

Comment: oh ok lo voy a probar y te aviso si quedo am te comento ya intente cambiar el Obdc por el Npgsql pero cuando lo cambio ya no funciona :$ que hago

Comment: mm que raro, se supone que con las clases de  Npgsql deberia funcionae mejor, igual ojo como defines el connection string porque no es el mismo que usas en odbc

Comment: oye al ejecutarlo me marca error en: return Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) > 0;

Comment: ya cambie mi conexion a Npgsql pero aun me marca error

Comment: NpgsqlConnection cn = new NpgsqlConnection("SERVER=localhost;UID=postgres;PWD=1234;DATABASE=ProyectoAsistencia;");